# ALTER PROCEDURE does not alter results

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures

I have a stored procedure in SQL Server that selects some customer pricing information based on a `CustomerID`. I need to combine this data with another query that simply adds a few extra columns. Although `ALTER PROCEDURE` executes successfully and the changes appear to have saved in the procedure, the result set on execution never changes. Even when I tried removing all but one field (just to see what would happen), the same old set of fields shows up.

I've tried refreshing the procedure every way I know how to - is there some sort of cache that needs to be cleared? I've never had this issue before.

Removing proprietary client data and a little bloat for simplicity, here is the meat of what I have in my `ALTER PROCEDURE`:

```
 SET ANSI_NULLS ON
 GO
 SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
 GO

 ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[getCustPrices] 
     @CustomerID AS VARCHAR(50) 
 AS

 IF (object_id('GetExtendedPricing') IS NOT NULL)
 BEGIN
   EXEC GetExtendedPricing @CustomerID
    ,@itemnmbr
    ,@itemdesc
   RETURN
 END

 /* drop old temp table if it's still around */
 IF (OBJECT_ID('CustHistoryTemp') IS NOT NULL)
 BEGIN
   DROP TABLE CustHistoryTemp
 END

 /* first data set */
 SELECT CustomerName, ItemNumber, SUM(CASE WHEN YEAR(DocDate) = YEAR(getdate())-2 THEN Qty ELSE 0 END) AS Qty2015
 INTO CustHistoryTemp
 FROM HistoricalCustomerData
 WHERE CustomerID = @CustomerID

 /* drop old temp table if it's still around */
 IF (OBJECT_ID('CustPricingTemp') IS NOT NULL)
 BEGIN
   DROP TABLE CustPricingTemp
 END

 /* second data set */
 SELECT PriceSheetID, Currency, StartDate, EndDate, ItemNum, Price
 INTO CustPricingTemp
 FROM CustPricing
 WHERE CustomerID = @CustomerID

 /* combine into result set? */
 SELECT CH.CustomerName, CH.ItemNumber, CH.Qty2015, CP.PriceSheetID, CP.Currency, CP.StartDate, CP.EndDate, CP.Price
 FROM CustHistoryTemp AS CH LEFT OUTER JOIN 
      CustPricingTemp AS CP ON CH.ItemNumber = CP.ItemNumber

 DROP TABLE CustHistoryTemp
 DROP TABLE CustPricingTemp
```

Results always include `CP.PriceSheetID`, `CP.Currency`, `CP.StartDate`, `CP.EndDate`, and `CP.Price`, whereas all columns from the other table are missing. Oddly, if I modify the final `SELECT` statement to only return a single column, the same 5 columns are STILL returned, making me wonder if I've made a logical error or if there might be something stuck in a cache somewhere, somehow.

It looks a little pointless to do it this way when a simple join query would work, but trust me - for this implementation I need to get this working in a stored procedure, so no need to lecture me about taking the hard road.

Thank you for any advice that might help point me in the right direction!

Comment: While this seems unlikely, is there any possibility that you're modifying the stored procedure in one database/schema, but testing in another?

Comment: @RDFozz It's the same database, I'm editing and testing it with Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio connected to the GP database. I'm not sure how it could cross wires with another database, the procedure shows up under the correct database GP->Programmability->Stored Procedures

Comment: From @ScottHodgin 's suggestion: is it possible that the actual SP does have multiple result sets, and you're not looking at the right one?

Comment: To test it I'm just right clicking -> Execute Stored Procedure...

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion but it doesn't seem to make a difference. I tried right-click Refresh, closed and re-opened Management Studio, tried executing it from a query window... same old results so far.

Comment: Script the stored procedure out as 'execute', then drop the stored procedure (making sure you have saved the actual T-SQL code for it).  Try to execute the stored procedure.  Does it fail with procedure not found?

Comment: You might also try simply stepping through the code via debug to see what's being executed.

Comment: You know what, I think I just figured it out... It was an error I had omitted (above the fold of what I included in my code above) which had short circuited the rest of the procedure. I'll go ahead and put that up in my code and let you answer if you'd like, might be helpful if there's anyone else dumb enough to make the same mistake as me :)

Comment: So, are you say that GetExtendedPricing got executed instead of the SP you were trying to change?  You can actually answer your own question since you were the one that figure it out :)

Comment: Yes, I had left that there from the procedure I had initially copied from because I wasn't sure what it was for and figured it was needed for some reason. Turns out it was executing another stored procedure that returned those 5 fields, so the second query at the bottom never had a chance. I guess I'll go ahead and answer it so we can close this out - I felt it wasn't fair not to give you a chance since I hadn't included all the pieces needed to answer the question from the start.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just remove `RETURN` after

```
EXEC GetExtendedPricing @CustomerID
  ,@itemnmbr
  ,@itemdesc
```

You exit your main procedure immediatety after executing `GetExtendedPricing`

Answer (score 0):

There are a few lines at the beginning of this `ALTER PROCEDURE` that are short circuiting all the effort below.

This piece in particular:

```
IF (object_id('GetExtendedPricing') IS NOT NULL)
BEGIN
 EXEC GetExtendedPricing @CustomerID
  ,@itemnmbr
  ,@itemdesc
 RETURN
END
```

This is executing another stored procedure which is, in this case, returning results before the lower query ever has a chance to run. That's why changes to the lower query didn't seem to make any difference in the results.

Removing those lines solves the problem.